# Unable to start Filebeat due to YAML config issue

Tags: yaml

I am new with filebeat and getting stuck on start up due to .yml configuration issue. I am working on Win7 professional.

I have configured default simple configuration:

```html
filebeat:
 prospectors:
  -
   paths:
    - "e:\Applications\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\logs\localhost_access_log.*.txt"
    - "e:\Applications\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\logs\*.log"
   input_type: log
```

No tabs are in the config. Validated by PSPad.

And depends on end of line I am getting following errors:

Using DOS:

> Loading config file error: YAML config parsing failed on apache.yml:
>   yaml: line 4: found unknown escape character. Exiting.

Using UNIX:

> Loading config file error: YAML config parsing failed on apache.yml:
>   yaml: line 3: could not find expected ':'. Exiting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The "unknown escape character" error is happening because `\A` is interpreted as an escape character in a quoted scalar. The simplest solution is to drop the quotes since they aren't necessary here (they usually aren't in YAML):

```yaml
filebeat:
 prospectors:
 - paths:
   - e:\Applications\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\logs\localhost_access_log.*.txt
   - e:\Applications\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\logs\*.log
   input_type: log
```

Alternatively, you could escape the backslashes with another backslash:

```yaml
filebeat:
 prospectors:
 - paths:
   - "e:\\Applications\\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\\logs\\localhost_access_log.*.txt"
   - "e:\\Applications\\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\\logs\\*.log"
   input_type: log
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps!

Answer (score 6):

As [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) points out, this is caused by backslashes being interpreted as escape sequences.

There are 2 possible workarounds:

1) Quote and Escape each Backslash:

```
- "e:\\Applications\\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\\logs\\*.log"
```

2) Remove the quotes *(but not that this doesn't work when the configuration parameter requires a list of strings)*

```
- e:\Applications\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\logs\*.log
```

If the configuration parameter requires list format `[]`, like `certificate_authorities`, then you must use workaround #1.

```
certificate_authorities: ["C:\\certs\\filebeat.crt"]
```

Also see https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/1495

Comment: Your comment about "list format" doesn't make any sense. Lists denoted by `[...]` ("flow" sequences) and lists denoted by lines beginning with `-` ("block" sequences) are deserialized to the exact same structure. Any list that can be represented in flow style can be represented in block style, and no tool will ever "require" one over the other (because they deserialize to the same thing). Take a look: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=foo%3A+%5B%22C%3A%5C%5Ccerts%5C%5Cfilebeat.crt%22%5D%0Abar%3A%0A-+C%3A%5Ccerts%5Cfilebeat.crt&type=json