# ELK Filebeat NLog logs processing

Tags: filebeat, elk

I did the config based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227876/can-filebeat-dissect-a-log-line-with-spaces) question, but it still doesn't work.

### Log string:

```
2021-11-19 23:55:45.1605|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7007
```

### filebeat.yml:

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - dissect:
     tokenizer: "%{} %{}|{%{level}|%{module}|%{msg}"
     field: "message"
     target_prefix: ""
```

In kibana I see that tokenizer doesn't work:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

## Update 21.11.2021 #1

Using `sidharth vijayakumar` example:

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
     host: "unix:///host_docker/docker.sock"
  - dissect:
     tokenizer: "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\|%{LOGLEVEL:level}\|%{GREEDYDATA:module}\|%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"
     field: "message"
     target_prefix: ""
```

But I got exception from filebeat:

```
Exiting: error loading config file: yaml: line 11: found unknown escape character
```

Comment: Detailed explanation is present here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513913/unable-to-start-filebeat-due-to-yaml-config-issue

Comment: \ is basically used for escape sequence but sometimes you need to use two \\ for the same. Just try this and check if it works :   "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\\|%{LOGLEVEL:level}\\|%{GREEDYDATA:module}\\|%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey can you try using this grok pattern.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\|%{LOGLEVEL:level}\|%{GREEDYDATA:module}\|%{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

[image: result of grok match]

You would be getting the entries as fields in elastic stack. I think you are facing issues cause your grok patterns don't match. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what I did, but this pattern works:

```
%{service:time}|%{service:level}|%{service:module}|%{service:msg}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great, if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).